# Running Android emulator via Cordova - AVD Manager missing from Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have spent a 2 days trying to set up a Cordova App and to run it in an android emulator following the instructions on this page (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) and relating pages.  I have encountered countless issues, the latest one being that the android emulator wont run.  When I run:

```
cordova emulate android
```

I get the following message which just stays there:

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5x_API_23_x86
Waiting for emulator.....
```

After searching for answers it seems I need to set up an Android Virtual Device (AVD).  I have therefore started following these instructions (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) as told to do so by the Cordova instructions but I dont have the AVD Manager option available in my Android Studio.

[image: Missing AVD Manager option under Tools]

I have the path to the SDK set up as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone help with this?  I am so fed up and confused by it all...

***********UPDATE**************

After the help below, I launched the AVD Manager from the Android SDK folder but came across the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont create the emulator in Android Studio. Instead create it with AVD Manager.exe

I suppose you have an android SDK folder (appart from the one created by Android Studio). In that SDK folder, you'll have AVD Manager.exe
Run the AVD Manager from there, create the virtual machine (emulator) and launch it.
Then use the appropriate cordova command to launch the app (in the running emulator ; created as I suggested)

In my case this is how the things work :

**Steps :**

- I have downloaded android SDK package (for instance from here http://www.filehippo.com/download_android_sdk) and saved for instance at C:\Android_SDK
- In that folder, you can download specific API level with `SDK Manager.exe`
  and create emulators with `AVD Manager.exe`
- Next create an emulator via `AVD Manager.exe` located where you saved the SDK package (here C:\Android_SDK)
- Launch (start) the emulator
- **WHEN THE EMULATOR IS DONE LOADING**, run `cordova build android` and `cordova emulate android` 
  (Don't forget to be in the working directory of your cordova project)
- VOILA !!!

Comment: So sorry for the late response, I haven't had chance to look at this since!!  I really appreciate your help but am stuck at the point where you say "Launch the emulator".  I have updated my query above to show the error I have.  Many thanks

Comment: The red cross on your `Nexus_5X` emulator indicates something is faulty with it. Maybe the emulator is missing proper settings. So you should check that. For now, I'd suggest you click on the tab `Device Definitions` and choose a pre-configured emulator that has about the same settings as your `Nexus_5x`. With the pre-configured emulator, the `start` button will be enabled. I'd also suggest you use the emulator name `Nexus S by Google` as it is less ressource expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing the whole "Android" option in the Tools subsection, so I would start by checking if the Menus and Toolbars to check if everything is ok. This is how it looks on my computer (it's the macOS version, but should be similar)

[image]

If you're missing that section, try "Adding after" the options you're missing. Anyway, you should be able to run the Android Virtual Device manager by running the AVD.exe command on the binary folder

Comment: So sorry I have not had chance to look at this until now!  I can't even find the "Menus & Toolbars" option.  Where is this please?